# Adding Additional Fields to Symfony Form before Submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, domcrawler

I'm using Goutte, https://github.com/fabpot/goutte, and have the following code,

```
$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', \Config::get('Eload2::url'));

$form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit')->form();

// add extra fields here

$client->submit($form);
```

how do I do to add hidden input fields to the form before it's submitted?

I tried the following code,

```
$domdocument = new \DOMDocument;

$formfield = new InputFormField ($domdocument->createElement('__EVENTTARGET', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLTelco'));

$formfield2 = new InputFormField ($domdocument->createElement('__EVENTARGUMENT',''));

$form->set($formfield); 

$form->set($formfield2);
```

but the following error message is returned,

> An InputFormField can only be created from an input or button tag (__EVENTTARGET given).

Answer (score 6):

What you are creating is this:

```
<__EVENTTARGET>ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLTelco</__EVENTTARGET>
<__EVENTARGUMENT />
```

While you want:

```
<input name="__EVENTTARGET" value="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLTelco" />
<input name="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
```

Try this:

```
$ff = $domdocument->createElement('input');
$ff->setAttribute('name', '__EVENTTARGET');
$ff->setAttribute('value', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLTelco');
$formfield = new InputFormField($ff);

$ff = $domdocument->createElement('input');
$ff->setAttribute('name', '__EVENTTARGET');
$ff->setAttribute('value', '');
$formfield2 = new InputFormField($ff);
```